# Remote program control using winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface

How I can remotely control a GUI program using winapi?

I need to open skype or icq and click on the right contact and then read the last message. There's a program in VS spy++, but if you want to trace window messages, you need to remotely control spy++. So the problem is how can you remotely control a program and the other thing, where can you find application codes.

Comment: No, but it's a good idea.

Comment: [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). Preemptive warning message: *UI Automation is designed for experienced C/C++ developers. In general, developers need a moderate level of understanding about Component Object Model (COM) objects and interfaces, Unicode, and Windows API programming.*

Comment: Mission impossible starts!

Comment: I suspect you're biting off a bit more than you can chew here; might want to start by just looking at something like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and when you have that figured out move on to simple "send program B a keystroke from program A" projects.

Comment: Can I do this with simple api, something like handling window, and then getMessage, f.e. from a text field?And if you be so nice to tell in a few words, what can I do with UI Automation.I read a lot of stuff on msdn, but it's all about control types and the word testing is used pretty often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [White framework](http://teststack.azurewebsites.net/white/index.html) hides a lot of the details of UI automation, and you may find it easier to use than raw [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).